# i need to replace the <mark> tag in a string with the contents inside that tag java script

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, string

i need to replace the  tag  inside a string with the contents inside that tag java script.That means i simply want to remove the start and the end tags , And the content should be there as such.

Suppose my input string is

```
<div class="active"><mark class="active-search-position">The Alliance for Child Protection</mark><mark class>The Alliance for Child Protection</mark></div>
```

The output String should be

```
<div class="active">The Alliance for Child ProtectionThe Alliance for Child Protection</div>
```

The below is the source code that i have tried out

```
temp = String(temp).replace(/<mark class="active-search-position">/gi,"").replace(/<mark class>/,"").replace(/<mark>/gi, "").replace(/<\/mark>/gi, "");
```

But this just partially working.Is there any regular expression by which i can match the  tag , and do the replace with a single line?

Comment: `$("mark.active-search-position).text()` will give you the full text without tags. `$("mark").text($("mark").text())` is all you need.

Comment: Thanks @MatJ Actually i am using angular.So what i need is a regular expression to match the <mark> tag.

Comment: @Pranavs updated my answer to remove only `<mark>` tag as per your question update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following :

```js
let htmlText = '<mark class="active-search-position">The Alliance for Child Protection</mark><mark class>The Alliance for Child Protection</mark>';

let plainText = htmlText.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');  // remove full html

console.log(plainText); // output : The Alliance for Child Protection


// updated answer to remove only <mark> tag as per question update 

let updatedContent = '<div class="active"><mark class="active-search-position">The Alliance for Child Protection</mark></div>';

let updatedText = updatedContent.replace(/(<mark[^>]*>|<\/mark>)/g, ''); 

console.log(updatedText); // output : <div class="active">The Alliance for Child Protection</div>
```

Comment: Thanks joel . This matches all the tags in that given string.I need to match the <mark> tag only. Because there is many other tags in my actual string.

Comment: Then provide a good example in your question. Your question does not show any other tags in the example.

Comment: @Pranavs how many of the `<mark>` text will be there ? is it just one or dynamic

Comment: @JoelJoseph There are many mark tags. For the time being assume that they are static.Thank you.

Comment: @Pranavs updated my answer, please see if this works for you